# what is io and socket?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm pretty confused with socket.io, I'm trying to create a simple chat server application in node.js by using socket.io. I have a few questions that I would like to ask please

```
var app = express();

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  io.emit('online');
  console.log('user is online');

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    io.emit('user is disconnected');
    console.log('user is disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('chat', function(msg) {
    console.log("message: " + msg);
    io.emit('chat', msg);
  });
  socket.broadcast.emit('user connected');
});

server.listen(3000);
```

1) Base on the above codes, I don't understand why do we need to call `io` variables again inside `io.on('connection')`, can i just use `socket` instead?

2) what is the `socket` variable? what is the difference between io and socket?

3) What is `io.emit` and `io.on` or `socket.emit` and `socket.on`?

I know that io is the socket.io server but why do we need to to use `io.emit` instead of `socket.emit`?

Please explain to me in details because I'm a newbie who just started learning node.js and socket.io. Please don't be too harsh on me :)

Comment: You need to learn more about Javascript and programming in general. The answers to these questions would be obvious to you if you had the pre-requisite knowledge. In other words, you're trying to build a spaceship without even knowing how to do algebra.

Comment: I recommend that you work through the nodeschool workshops if you're new to node, rather than just trying to build an app yourself right at the start, http://nodeschool.io/#workshoppers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`io.on()` This is registering an event handler for a specific event. That is when the object raises that specific event your code will be called. So in this context `io` is your socket.io server object. When a client connects it will raise the connect event allowing you to handle it.

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events

`socket` is your handle on that specific client connection. It allows you to communicate directly with that client. `emit` and `on` allows you to listen to events from that specific client or emit events to that specific client.

`io.emit` allows you to emits events to all connected clients.

http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit

Your example appears to be a chat message app. Your using `io.emit` not `socket.emit` because you want to send the message out to all connected clients when a user types a message or connects.

But this is basic stuff that's all in the docs.

Comment: so if I use socket.emit it will send to one client only?

Comment: That is correct, the socket has information as to the specific client it relates to. You can also do things like but clients or `socket`'s into different groups and emit to just clients in that group

Comment: .on is like a listener while .emit is send?